# Finding sub-string in a string while both of them are user inputs

Tags: c++, string, substring

I have written this program to find sub-string in a string while both of them are user inputs.This is working fine albeit approach may seems amateur to quite a few here.My problem is that when I put the string "a" and "b" as the following:"I am kamlesh" and "am" respectively. 
I am NOT GETTING any output while omitting "a[t4]==' '" in the last if statement giving me output 3 and 7.
Please suggest some ways to rectify and getting the output as 3 only. 
Post edit:Working fine now.

```
/* #include <iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;
void substring(char *a,char *b);

int main()
{
char a[80],b[80];
gets(a);
gets(b);
substring(a,b);

return 0;
}
void substring(char *a,char *b)
{
int c,d;
c=strlen(a);
d=strlen(b);
for(int t=0;t<c;t++)
{
    if(a[t] && a[t]==*b)
    {
        int t1,t2,t3,t4;
        t2=1;
        t1=d-1;
        t3=t+1;
        while(t1 && a[t3]==b[t2] )
        {
        t1--;
        t3++;
        t2++;
        t4=t2;
        }

        if(!t1 && a[t4]==' ') //to avoid showing "am" in kamlesh. 
            cout<<t+1<<endl;
      }
   }
 } */

#include <iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;
void substring(char *a,char *b);

 int main()
  {
char a[80],b[80];
int s;
gets(a);
gets(b);
substring(a,b);

return 0;
}
void substring(char *a,char *b)
{
char *s1,*s2;

for(int t=0;a[t];t++)
{
   s1=&a[t];
   s2=b;
    while(*s2 && *s2==*s1)
    {
        s1++;
        s2++;
    }
    if(*s2 && *s1==' ')
       cout<<t;
   }

  }
```

Comment: This is like a puzzle.  The variable names convey no meaning and are really hard to follow.  There are almost zero comments to describe the approach you are taking.  I think if you clear up these issues, you won't need any help -- your problem will likely become obvious and the solution easy.

Comment: Don't edit your question with a "fix" that makes it go away! Instead, if no anwers answer your question and you do find "an answer", post that as an Answer!

Comment: Sorry, I would keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

As donjuedo said, this code is very unreadable. Things that I see quickly is that a[t4] is problematic because there is no guarantee that t4 is going to be initialized before that; you don't need to walk backwards from the end of your substring (t1); and you don't need to use indexing with integers to walk around in the strings, you can move pointers around.

The code should be something as simple as:

```
char* p1 = (char*)str; // the string to be searched
int substrIndex = 0;

while (*p1) {
   char* p1Begin = p1;                 // keep the pos of start of search
   char* p2 = (char*)target;           // pointer for the substring

   while (*p1 && *p2 && *p1 == *p2) {  // as long as within the boundaries, chars equal
      p1++;
      p2++;
   }

   if (!*p2)  // if all chars equal, passed end of target - success
      cout << substrIndex << endl;

   p1 = p1Begin + 1;
   substrIndex++;
}
```

I didn't compile, so not 100% sure it will run bug free; but you get the idea.